# issue with selecting data from the data base

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

am using this code to display text on the edit page that the user already comment it and I want to let them edit it if they want but I have a problem am using mysqli_num_rows to check if they result or not I get no result from the database. why this happening am I selecting from the database using the wrong way

```
    $editsql = "SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_by, posts.post_id, posts.post_topic,
posts.post_content
FROM topics, posts WHERE posts.post_topic = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['id'])." ";
$editresult = mysqli_query($conn,$editsql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($editresult) == 0)
  {
      echo 'something went wrong please try again later';
  }
      while ($editrow= mysqli_fetch_assoc($editresult)) {
  $topic_by = $editrow['topic_by'];
  if ($_SESSION['id'] = $topic_by) {
  echo '<form method="post" action="'.edit_function($conn).'" class="textareacon bottom">
      <textarea name="edit-content">'.$editrow['post_content'].'</textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit reply" name="edit-post" class="topicsubmit"/>
  </form>';
}else {
  echo "sorry look like you've been redirected to the wrong topic please head back and try again";
}



}
```

Comment: [PHP delusion #1: Mysql(i)_real_escape_string prevents SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/top#escaping)

Comment: [PHP delusion #5: Extensive use of the number of rows returned by a SELECT query](https://phpdelusions.net/top#num_rows)

Comment: If you completely change the question, you should rather close and reopen a new question

Comment: I can't for some odd reason it says that I should wait a number of days to post a new question

Comment: then you should wait as it says

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are trying to get your result when there are none. Please change your code as below and try. I also changed the `=` to `==` in `$_SESSION['id'] = $topic_by`

```
$editsql = "SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_by, posts.post_id, posts.post_topic, posts.post_content FROM topics, posts WHERE posts.post_topic = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['id'])." ";

$editresult = mysqli_query($conn,$editsql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($editresult) == 0) {
    echo 'something went wrong please try again later';
} else {
      while ($editrow= mysqli_fetch_assoc($editresult)) {
          $topic_by = $editrow['topic_by'];
          if ($_SESSION['id'] == $topic_by) {
              echo '<form method="post" action="'.edit_function($conn).'" class="textareacon bottom"><textarea name="edit-content">'.$editrow['post_content'].'</textarea><input type="submit" value="Submit reply" name="edit-post" class="topicsubmit"/></form>';
          } else {
              echo "sorry look like you've been redirected to the wrong topic please head back and try again";
          }
      }
}
```

> One personal note : please try using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and/or [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: am trying to get a result from my forum system everything is setup correctly the topics and the posts I just want to allow the user how made the topic to be able to edit it. am trying to select the topic subject to show it for the user to edit it but it won't show the topic already exists and the post to but for some odd reason it tells me nothing found the the database

Comment: have you tried running your query against the database without php, through something like PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: does mysqli safe from haking or not and what the differences between mysqli and PDO

Comment: mysqli is not safe all alone by itself, and the differences between PDO and mysqli is one google away from you. There are hundreds of articles about this subject (if not thousands). Please accept this answer if it solved your problems, or ask questions related to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem look like it was in my topic page

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  if ($_SESSION['id'] = $post_by) {
      echo '<br /><a class="edit_topic" href="edit-topic.php?id='.$row['id'].' ">Edit</a><br /><br />';
  }
}
```

i used a row from the database , i should of use get id from the url

```
  if ($_SESSION['id'] = $post_by) {
      $get_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['id']);
      echo '<br /><a class="edit_topic" href="edit-topic.php?id='.$get_id.' ">Edit</a><br /><br />';
  }
```

thanks for help my problem fixed

Comment: this line of code `if ($_SESSION['id'] = $post_by) {` is wrong unless you are trying to assign `$post_by`'s value to `$_SESSION['id']`. It should be `if ($_SESSION['id'] == $post_by) {`

Comment: $post_by = $row['post_by']; i already assigned a value to the post_by

Comment: Yes but using only 1 equal sign you assign all that you have read to session value

Comment: I just adjust it to 2 equal. do you have any answer for my new Q above

Comment: You need to post a new question. You can't just edit and ask more in 1 post.